# Price and VAT in opencart 2.x

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I m using opencart 2.x for development and i am really stuck in `cart` and `invoices`. My scenario is that,

> I want to show VAT only while sending invoice to the customer and VAT shall not be visible in Cart but total in cart shall be including VAT.

What I want is to not display the tax in cart and if I disable it in the admin screen it does not count up correctly and is not appearinf in Invoice as well. So it must be hidden in the code.

**Presentation in Cart shall be**

```
Subtotal // This subtotal shall inclusive of VAT here
Shipping
Total  // This total shall inclusive of VAT here
```

**Presentation in Invoice shall be**

```
Subtotal  // This subtotal shall exclusive of VAT here
Shipping
VAT(1%) // VAT is shown here
Total  // This total shall inclusive of VAT here
```

Currently, i have presenation in cart and invoice same as of invoice shown above.

I have enabled Taxes in `Extensions > Order Totals` but i do not know how to modify the total array in opencart.

Comment: it's very easy. all model on total folder only you need to change getTotal() method of all model

Comment: Can you please explain and post that as answer and then will i be able to get diff in cart and invoice?

Comment: You want skip TAX from cart and from invoice

Comment: I want to skip VAT from only cart and confirm page at checkout and VAT shall be included in cart's total by default. But in invoice VAT shall be there and it ll b added to total while sending invoice

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace code :--

catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php

Find Below code :--

```
foreach ($results as $result) 
{
    if ($this->config->get($result['code'] . '_status')) 
    {
        $this->load->model('total/' . $result['code']);
        $this->{'model_total_' . $result['code']}->getTotal($total_data, $total, $taxes);
    }
}
```

Replace with This Code :--

```
foreach ($results as $result) 
{
    if ($this->config->get($result['code'] . '_status')) 
    {
        $this->load->model('total/' . $result['code']);
        if($result['code'] != "tax")
        {
            $this->{'model_total_' . $result['code']}->getTotal($total_data, $total, $taxes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have not understood the question properly nor you have read my comment to your question... I want TAX not be displayed in Cart but VAT shall be added to TOTAL in CART>... It is just matter of not showing it... While in Invoice TAX shall be visible...

Comment: I did understand wrong. You need total with vat but vat not display in cart correct?